# Read an Image/file from External storage Android

Tags: java, android, image, file-io, bitmap

I'm trying to load an image from external storage. I set the permissions, I tried different ways, but none of them works.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.toString()); 

    tv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

and this one,

```
FileInputStream streamIn = new FileInputStream(file);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(streamIn); 

    tv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        streamIn.close();
```

Comment: what is tv in the above code. is it a textview?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, since I put in a try and catch, but the application crashes if I don't have it.                        ImageView tv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

Comment: **Don't use silent catch blocks during debugging.**  Make sure you at least print the stack trace of any Exceptions - otherwise you are left guessing, and end up posting an incomplete question.  Voting to close the question on that grounds, and because you apparently resolved your problem a year ago anyway.

Answer (score 25):

If i have file `abc.jpg` on the `sdcard` then:

```
String photoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/abc.jpg";
```

and to get `bitmap`.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
```

or

```
Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);
```

**to avoide out of memory error** I suggest you use the below code...

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;
final Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
```

---

To avoid above issue you can use **Picasso** (A powerful image downloading and caching library for Android)

[Documentation](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

How To?

```
Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView3);
```

Comment: I got it working, I guess the way I had it was fine, the problem was that I was trying to run it as a function, and then call a function, it works if I don't use functions. I'm not sure why it doesn't work when I use functions. Where would you define the function and where can you call it?

Comment: if I use this one " options.inSampleSize = 8; " image becoming very small and clarity also decreasing.

Answer (score 5):

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures");

File file = new File(directory, "image_name.jpg"); //or any other format supported

FileInputStream streamIn = new FileInputStream(file);

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(streamIn); //This gets the image

streamIn.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the path of the image from your folder as below. And then decode the file as a bitmap.

```
   File file= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Your folder");
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file path, just use BitmapFactory directly, but tell it to use a format that preserves alpha:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
selected_photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called

```
createFromPath(String)
```

in the Drawable class.
So the statement

```
String path="/storage/..<just type in the path>";
Drawable.createFromPath(path);
```

will return a drawable object