# Best way to download image from URL and save it into internal storage memory

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which I want to download image from URL. I need to download these images at once and stored it into  internal storage. There are more than 200 images for downloading. Please tell me the best way to download these images at minimum time possible. If any third part library is available the please tell.

Comment: You may use Picasso or Volley

Comment: picasso does not save these images into internal storage. it directly shows on ui

Comment: You can use Volley lib and create a custom Request that write your image directly in the device memory on success response.

Comment: you might want to take a look at this post of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549421/how-to-download-and-save-an-image-in-android

Comment: Use AQuery for this. It store images in both memory cache and local storage.

check: https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading

Comment: You want to download 200 at a single shot or you want to implement lazy loading of images in listview?

Answer (score 35):

Consider using Picasso for your purpose. I'm using it in one of my project. To save image on external disk you can use following:

```
 Picasso.with(mContext)
        .load(ImageUrl)
        .into(new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                try {
                    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                    File myDir = new File(root + "/yourDirectory");

                    if (!myDir.exists()) {
                        myDir.mkdirs();
                    }

                    String name = new Date().toString() + ".jpg";
                    myDir = new File(myDir, name);
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myDir);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

                    out.flush();
                    out.close();                        
                } catch(Exception e){
                    // some action
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            }
        }
    );
```

[From here](http://square.github.io/picasso/) you can download this library.

Comment: i want to download 200 images. for that i need to loop to download these images

Comment: @astuter can you explain me how to retrieve the image after saving it?

Comment: @Signo:  Check the answer of Dhawal Shoda parmar, in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15918369/2571277

Comment: @astuter thank you very much for the quick response! :) I tried but with no luck, it says there's nothing if the ExternalStorage, now I'll do a little bit of debug to find out what's the issue, thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks! i'm new in android and that was very helpful.

Comment: @UmeshKumarSaraswat you can retrieve the image from local file system  as `Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView)`;

Comment: Better to create name as  String name = new Date().getTime() + ".jpg"; if you have morethan 1 image to download at a time.

Answer (score 9):

You can download th image from an url like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/image_to_read.jpg");
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int n = 0;
while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
{
   out.write(buf, 0, n);
}
out.close();
in.close();
byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
```

And you may then want to save the image so do:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C://borrowed_image.jpg");
fos.write(response);
fos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) holder.post_image.getDrawable();
                        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(mContext.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "IMG_" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), null);
```

It is quite a simple job...

Answer (score 0):

```
 const actionDownloadImage = (urls) => {
        urls.map((url) => {
            const splitUrl = url.split("/");
            const filename = splitUrl[splitUrl.length - 1];
            fetch(url)
                .then((response) => {
                    response.arrayBuffer().then(function (buffer) {
                        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([buffer]));
                        const link = document.createElement("a");
                        link.href = url;
                        link.setAttribute("download", filename); //or any other extension
                        document.body.appendChild(link);
                        link.click();
                        document.body.removeChild(link);
                    });
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        });
    }
```