# Android - Recyclerview adapter show Images from External Storage

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I want create image gallery with RecyclerView where use images from phone. I didn't find any RecyclerView adapter which fill image with File type. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For basic functionality of RecyclerView adapters: http://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-RecyclerView

In your `onBindViewHolder`, you can get your image like this:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myImage.jpg";
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
```

([more info on getting images from external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918335/read-an-image-file-from-external-storage-android))

and use it with an ImageView or something similar.

Comment: Thank you.. I wrote adapter by use Bitmap

Answer (score 1):

It's works

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
    holder.countryName.setText("Img");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(newList.get(position));
    holder.countryPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```