# Open an image from the external storage

Tags: java, android, uri, android-external-storage

I've been trying for several hours to open an image from Android's external storage with `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`. And as you might have figured out already, I'm still not able to do that.

I've searched all over Google and I've tried a lot of ways to make this work, however none of them did. All what I could find are questions that are up to 1 year old. I tried using `FileProvider` and here's what I ended up with:

```
File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "LyceeLamartine/cache");
File newFile = new File(imagePath, "calendrier.png");
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "ml.toufic.lyceelamartine.fileprovider", newFile);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

The code above opens Google Photos successfully but it shows a black screen and the path seems to be: `content://ml.toufic.lyceelamartine.fileprovider/name/calendrier.png` and this seems like an internal storage path.

The image I want to access is stored at: "/storage/emulated/0/LyceeLamartine/cache/calendrier.png" and I'm using a phone with Android O (8.0).

I'm still a beginner in Java and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: see hear if helpful for u :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918335/read-an-image-file-from-external-storage-android

Comment: Thanks Mohammad for your fast reply but, unfortunately, I'm not trying to open an image inside an `imageView` when I really want to use `intent` to open it and it's from 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the path seems to be: content://ml.toufic.lyceelamartine.fileprovider/name/calendrier.png and this seems like an internal storage path.

That is not a path. That is a `Uri`. It has a scheme (`content`). It points to your `FileProvider` (`ml.toufic.lyceelamartine.fileprovider`). It seems fine — if there were a problem with the `Uri`, `FileProvider` would have thrown an exception when you tried to create it.

> The code above opens Google Photos successfully but it shows a black screen

There are two problems with your `Intent`.

First, do not use a wildcard MIME type. It is *your* file. *You* know what the MIME type is. Use the actual MIME type (in this case, `image/png`).

Second, call `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` on the `Intent` as part of setting it up, before calling `startActivity()`. Right now, no app has rights to use your content.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! You saved me, I was trying to fix this for hours!! I think it's the `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` that made it work. Accepting this right now!

Comment: Any idea on how to check if the file is present? @CommonsWare

Comment: @TouficBatache: `newFile.exists()`.